# [ansible]; working with multiple dictionary

Tags: python, centos, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to run the following ::

[Press to see code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3qv7.png)

```
   - name: Snapshot BI nodes
     hosts: [CLUSTER-BI,CLUSTER-BI-REPLACE]
      vars_files:
        - snapshot_vars.yml 
     user: root
     any_errors_fatal: true
     tasks:

       - name: step 1
         shell: "{{item.value}} &> {{snapshot_dir}}/ETL/{{item.key}}.log"
         with_dict: "{{ ETL }}"

       - name: step 2
         shell: "{{item.value}} &> {{snapshot_dir}}/MSTR/{{item.key}}.log"
         with_dict: "{{ MSTR }}"
```

getting error after step 1
How do I set a new dic for each step

Comment: Please show the error.

Comment: There is no error it is just not proceeding to step 2.
and if I inverse between them it will do step 2 and not 1.

Comment: Just a guess, is this related to the use of the ampersand `&`? What happens if you remove those `&` characters and try running it? I realise you may want this behaviour, but lets see if the whole thing runs without them first, then work out how to deliver the behaviour you want.

Comment: I tried to remove it, it does not work.

Comment: please add the vars ETL and MSTR

Comment: run the playbook with -vvv , u will see the command executed and also stdout/stderr

Answer (score 0):

This works without the & :

```
---
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    ETL:
      file1: "echo hello etl"
      file2: "echo hello2 etl"
    MSTR:
      file3: "echo hello3 mstr"
      file4: "echo hello4 mstr"
  tasks:
  - name: step 1
    shell: "{{item.value}} > /tmp/ETL/{{item.key}}.log"
    with_dict: "{{ ETL }}"

  - name: step 2
    shell: "{{item.value}} > /tmp/MSTR/{{item.key}}.log"
    with_dict: "{{ MSTR }}"
```

I end up with 4 files ( the ETL/MSTR folders must exists )

```
/tmp/ tree
.
├── ETL
│   ├── file1.log
│   └── file2.log
├── MSTR
│   ├── file3.log
│   └── file4.log
```